# Merge cells to pipe separted cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

we have gotten an Excel file of contacts with emails.
There can be multiple rows for the same email, but with multiple job titles.

We might see

```
john@doe.com Carpenter
john@doe.com Farmer
```

But we should have these job titles pipe separated like this:

```
john@doe.com Carpenter||Farmer
```

Comment: You'll need `TEXTJOIN` function to do this or else go with a VBA solution.

Comment: You can do this easily with `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform`